# Process for loop inside AJAX (Synchronous)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can I perform synchronous in this scenario? I have a header and once pulled I put the AJAX inside to pull its details and populate fields.

```
$.ajax({
  url: base_url + "order/get_order/" + id,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(data) {
    var trankey = data.TranKey;
    $('[name="transactionkey"]').val(trankey);
    $('[name="qty"]').val(data.OrderQTY);
    loadStorer(1);
    loadSku(1);
    loadPNC(data.TruckerCode, data.PNC);
    $('[name="trucker"]').val(data.TruckerCode);
    $('[name="sku"]').val(data.sku);

    $.getJSON(base_url + "order/get_details/" + trankey, function(data) {
      if (data !== "") {
        fill_data(data);
      }
    });
  },
  async: false,
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error get data from ajax');
  }
});

function fill_data(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i >= data.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      add_row();
    }
    $('#store_code' + i).val(data[i]['StoreCode']);
    $('#sku' + i).val(data.data[i]['sku']);
    $('#ret_qty' + i).val(data[i]['ReturnedQty']);
    $('#shipped_qty' + i).val(data[i]['ShippedQty']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, remove the `async: false` setting on your AJAX request. That's very bad practice. Secondly, the `for` loop you refer to is *already* synchornous.

Comment: your outer AJAX is synchronous but the inner $.getJSON (also an AJAX call) is asynchronous. But it's irrelevant because the `for` loop is executed within the callback of the getJSON, so it won't fire until getJSON finishes (which is correct). After that the loop executes synchronously. I don't see the problem. As Rory says though, remove `async:false` - you don't need it. It's also deprecated in most browsers (due to the terrible user experience it produces, freezing the browser during the Ajax call) and so you can expect it to stop working entirely in future.

Comment: If you can describe an actual bug in your code which you're experiencing - i.e. describe some behaviour you expected, compared with what is actually happening when you run the code, then we might be able to help you. Right now there's no obvious issue to deal with.

Comment: hi all , thanks for the response .. I already removed `async:false` but it is still not working.. its not executing whats inside the for loop.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, heres the screenshot of the modal [create row and populate.PNG](https://prnt.sc/kqu3rh)
when I click edit button that modal pops up and on my code I populated the header and on the details it will create row, the function add_row() and fill it by the function fill_data() but as you can see its not creating row and populating data.

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's Console for errors? Have you set breakpoints to see which lines of code are being executed and which are not? Maybe the JSON data return by $.getJSON doesn't match what the fill_data() function is expecting. That could cause a crash. We can't see your data. So please show us the JSON, and/or do some more detailed debugging of your own. Saying "It's not working" or "it's not executing" does not give us an adequate amount of information to allow us to help you, and also suggests that you haven't properly investigated the circumstances yet.

Comment: Also we can't see your HTML, so we don't know if you're using the correct IDs for your elements, and we can't see your add_row() function, so if there are problems in there we wouldn't be able to diagnose them. Lots of missing pieces of the puzzle here.

Comment: html and add_rows are working well, also IDs are correct .. Here's my [HTML](https://pastebin.com/27eeMYhV) and [JAVASCRIPT](https://pastebin.com/UD2tuwVy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the comments. .. 
I just missed my for loop it must be i

```
function fill_data(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      add_row();
    }
    $('#store_code' + (i+1)).val(data[i]['StoreCode']);
    $('#sku' + (i+1)).val(data.data[i]['sku']);
    $('#ret_qty' + (i+1)).val(data[i]['ReturnedQty']);
    $('#shipped_qty' + (i+1)).val(data[i]['ShippedQty']);
  }
}
```

Thanks!